# How do I extract data from a dynamicly created table ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got table, generated by this code (I know it looks bad but it just as a test):

```
 protected void Gen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> ParamList = new List<string>();
            ParamList.Add("Perforation");
            ParamList.Add("Top of perforation");
            ParamList.Add("Bottom of perforation");
            ParamList.Add("Well radius");
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                TableRow row1=new TableRow();
                TableCell cell1=new TableCell();
                cell1.BorderColor=System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
                cell1.BorderWidth=2;
                cell1.Font.Size = 11;
                cell1.Text=ParamList.ElementAt(i);
                TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
                cell2.BorderColor=System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
                cell2.BorderWidth=2;
                cell2.Width = 200;
                TextBox text1 = new TextBox();
                text1.ID = "txtb_1" + i;
                text1.Width = cell2.Width;
                text1.Height = cell2.Height;
                cell2.Controls.Add(text1);
                TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
                cell3.BorderColor=System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
                cell3.BorderWidth=2;
                cell3.Width = 200;
                DropDownList dlist = new DropDownList();
                dlist.ID = "dlist_1" + i;
                ListItem li1 = new ListItem("m");
                ListItem li2 = new ListItem("ft");
              //  if (i != 0)
               // {
                    dlist.Items.Add(li1);
                    dlist.Items.Add(li2);
             //   }
                dlist.Width = cell3.Width;
                dlist.Height = cell3.Height;
                cell3.Controls.Add(dlist);
                row1.Cells.Add(cell1);
                row1.Cells.Add(cell2);
                row1.Cells.Add(cell3);
                row1.ID = "id" + i;
                ParamTable.Rows.Add(row1);
            }
        }
```

So how do I can get data from `dropdownlist` and `textbox` elements on it? I assume that I could use elements `ID` somehow to call  them, but I can't find any example.

**UPD:** aspx

```
          <asp:Table CssClass="span9"  style="margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:5px;"   ID="ParamTable" runat="server">
                   <asp:TableHeaderRow >
                                <asp:TableHeaderCell  Font-Size="Medium" BorderColor="DarkGray" BorderWidth="2px"  >Parameters</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                <asp:TableHeaderCell  Font-Size="Medium" BorderColor="DarkGray" BorderWidth="2px" >Value</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                <asp:TableHeaderCell  Font-Size="Medium" BorderColor="DarkGray" BorderWidth="2px" >Units</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                   <asp:TableRow >
              </asp:TableRow>
           </asp:Table>
```

Comment: is it your window application or web application ?

Comment: Do you want to get data for selected row only or for all rows ?

Comment: @SpiderCode for all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below code to get the value of each row :

```
for (int i = 0; i < ParamTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var textBoxValue = ((TextBox)ParamTable.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("txtb_1" + i)).Text;
    var dropDownValue = ((DropDownList)ParamTable.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("dlist_1" + i)).SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

**Note:** I don't store values in any list. You can use POCO/Property class as per your requirement.

**Update:**

Remove `<asp:TableRow ></asp:TableRow>` from aspx and update forloop as mentioned below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ParamTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    var textBoxValue = ((TextBox)ParamTable.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("txtb_1" + i)).Text;
    var dropDownValue = ((DropDownList)ParamTable.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("dlist_1" + i)).SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Comment: oh but for some reason there are `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` appears after it pass the first row

Comment: have you changed anything in the code I have given ?

Comment: but when I call elements not into the `for` cycle but one by one its okay

Comment: one thing I have notices that in aspx table id is **table1** while you are using **ParamTable**